# Set the JSON Key to increment inside a loop

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an array within my json output from a php file which uses the key 0,1,2 etc

I am having trouble accessing the key through javascript. I'm not sure what the issue is with using numbers. All the other data has a text value key which I can access using data.arrayname.key. To get around the issue I would like to set the key to a string with a number at the end so I can reference it back in javascript easily.

The array is pushed to each time in a loop. Within the loop I have tried

```
 $NoOfTips++;
 $jsonKey = 'Tip' + $NoOfTips;
 $TBarray[$jsonKey]=$line;
 array_push($TBarray);
```

In theory each time the loop goes round NoOfTips should increase by 1 which would also change the key to Tip1,Tip2,etc but obviously something is amiss. Could somebody please explain how why the Key is not being set correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the real issue - to access a numeric index in javascript, you can't use dot notation, you would instead use brackets:

```
var data = { tips: { 1: "one", 2: "two" }, other: [1, { test: "tested" }] }
console.log(data.tips[1], data.other[0], data.other[1].test)
// output: one 1 tested
```

For the php side, when you do `array_push`, you have to specify the array you are pushing to, as well as what you are pushing:

```
array_push($TBarray, $line)
```

for example.  I'm not sure what you are going for there, though.

Comment: Thanks. Was having trouble getting my head around this and obviously was complicating the problem.